# How to get Google Places API - Place "types" to an array programmatically using JavaScript?

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible to get the Place "types" of Google Places API to an array programmatically using JavaScript? Any function in the API that provides this info.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of such functionality in Google Maps APIs.